# How to remove thick line when a table exceeds the margin

Tags: tables, margins

When a table exceeds the margins i get this bold line , how can i get rid of it ?
[image]

Comment: that is (most likely) the overfull box rule you get in `[draft]` mode, so you could remove draft but better to fix your table so that it is not so wide. But in general if you want help with some code you need to show the code.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem, you were right, setting the \overfullrule to 0 pt fixes the issue

Comment: "Fixed" is not the proper adjective here.  What you mean is that the `\overfullrule` is hidden.  Whether or not that is a problem depends on how much wider the table is than the text width.